# Does anybody know if exists a solution for this bug?

Tags: 13.10, network-manager, vpn

I have been using ubuntu 13.10 (amd64bits) for a while and always the same problem happen with me when I add a new VPN connection.

My problem is the same as described in the follow website -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1227186

The process name with bug is : nm-connection-editor.
I also try to kill the process but without success.

Obs.: Between first problem (+-7months ago) and today, I had updated my OS a few times, the bug still alive! One important thing about kill the process, if I do not kill, the process still using around 30% of my CPU, but if I kill the process, then it turn to 0% CPU usage, but still showing as a process alive. ;(

Any idea how to get around??

Comment: create a launchpad account and subscribe to the bug, you would be notified of new events(like fixes) for the bug.

Comment: I think it is not exactly duplicate cause it is version 13.10 and not 10.10.